svg stops working when position in html page changes
I am using the svg widget below from this answered question
Capture Signature using HTML5 and iPad
to create a capturable signature. The code as is works but when I put content above it such as text in a <p> tag it's stops working, which is problematic as I need it at the bottom of a document. Does anyone know why it stops working and how to make it work no matter where it is positioned in the html page?


//init
let r = document.getElementById('r'),
  p = document.getElementById('p'),
  signaturePath = '',
  isDown = false,
  svg = document.getElementById('sig_panel'),
  b_show = document.getElementById('show'),
  b_clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
  pathdata = document.getElementById('pathdata');

//drawing functions
function isTouchEvent(e) {
  return e.type.match(/^touch/);
}

function getCoords(e) {
  if (isTouchEvent(e)) {
    return e.targetTouches[0].clientX + ',' + e.targetTouches[0].clientY;
  }
  return e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY;
}

function down(e) {
  signaturePath += 'M' + getCoords(e) + ' ';
  p.setAttribute('d', signaturePath);
  isDown = true;

  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
}

function move(e) {
  if (isDown) {
    signaturePath += 'L' + getCoords(e) + ' ';
    p.setAttribute('d', signaturePath);
  }

  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
}

function up(e) {
  isDown = false;

  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
}

//input handlers
r.addEventListener('touchstart', down, false);
r.addEventListener('touchmove', move, false);
r.addEventListener('touchend', up, false);
r.addEventListener('mousedown', down, false);
r.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
r.addEventListener('mouseup', up, false);
r.addEventListener('mouseout', up, false);

//helper functions
function clearSignature() {
  pathdata.textContent = '';
  signaturePath = '';
  p.setAttribute('d', '');
}

function getSignature() {
  pathdata.textContent = signaturePath;
  return signaturePath;
}

//button handlers
b_show.addEventListener('click', getSignature);
b_clear.addEventListener('click', clearSignature);
svg {
  margin: .5em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: .5em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

button {
  margin: .5em;
}

#pathdata {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em .5em;
}
<svg id="sig_panel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <rect id="r" width="300" height="100" fill="#ffa"/>
  <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="300" y2="80" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3" shape-rendering="crispEdges" pointer-events="none"/>
  <path id="p" stroke="navy" stroke-width="2" fill="none" pointer-events="none"/>
</svg>
<div class="flex">
  <button id="show">Show signaure path data</button>
  <button id="clear">Clear signature</button>
</div>
<div id="pathdata"></div>




You need to convert screen coordinates to SVG user units as expalined here "How to convert svg element coordinates to screen coordinates?"
Now you can easily scale your SVG without messing up the coordinates.
Basically you only need to update the getCoords(e) function


//init
let r = document.getElementById('r'),
  p = document.getElementById('p'),
  signaturePath = '',
  isDown = false,
  svg = document.getElementById('sig_panel'),
  b_show = document.getElementById('show'),
  b_clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
  pathdata = document.getElementById('pathdata');


//drawing functions
function isTouchEvent(e) {
  return e.type.match(/^touch/);
}

function getCoords(e) {
  let pt

  if (isTouchEvent(e)) {
    pt = new DOMPoint(e.targetTouches[0].clientX, e.targetTouches[0].clientY);

  } else {
    pt = new DOMPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }

  // get Svg transform matrix
  let ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();

  // convert screen to SVG coordinates
  pt = pt.matrixTransform(ctm);

  // round coordinates   
  let decimals = 1;
  return `${+pt.x.toFixed(decimals)} ${+pt.y.toFixed(decimals)}`;
}

function down(e) {
  signaturePath += 'M' + getCoords(e) + ' ';
  p.setAttribute('d', signaturePath);
  isDown = true;

  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
}

function move(e) {
  if (isDown) {
    signaturePath += getCoords(e) + ' ';
    p.setAttribute('d', signaturePath);
  }

  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
}

function up(e) {
  isDown = false;

  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
}

//input handlers
r.addEventListener('touchstart', down, false);
r.addEventListener('touchmove', move, false);
r.addEventListener('touchend', up, false);
r.addEventListener('mousedown', down, false);
r.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
r.addEventListener('mouseup', up, false);
r.addEventListener('mouseout', up, false);

//button handlers
b_show.addEventListener('click', getSignature);
b_clear.addEventListener('click', clearSignature);

//helper functions
function clearSignature() {
  pathdata.textContent = '';
  signaturePath = '';
  p.setAttribute('d', '');
}

function getSignature() {
  pathdata.textContent = signaturePath;
  return signaturePath;
}
svg {
  margin: .5em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: .5em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

button {
  margin: .5em;
}

#pathdata {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em .5em;
}
<svg id="sig_panel" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <rect id="r" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ffa"/>
  <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="300" y2="80" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3" shape-rendering="crispEdges" pointer-events="none" />
  <path id="p" stroke="navy" stroke-width="2" fill="none" pointer-events="none"/>
</svg>
<div class="flex">
  <button id="show">Show signaure path data</button>
  <button id="clear">Clear signature</button>
</div>
<div id="pathdata"></div>



BTW. you can also save some bytes by omitting the L command lettters and apply some coordinate rounding.
You may also play with some simplification curve smoothing techniques as described here "SVG smooth freehand drawing"
